# Replace value of certain row in csv based on string value of adjacent row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I replace value of rows in column 'B' if the rows of column 'A' has a (string) supposed I have an existing csv. Like if `Dog` is in row, change it's adjacent row in column B

I'm looking for something like this:

```
for i in df['A']:
if i =='Dog','Cat': 
//replace value Black in column B to White
```

**Example:**

Original CSV

```
A,B
Dog,Black
Cat,Black
Mouse,Black
Pig,Black
```

Replaces to:

```
A,B
Dog,White
Cat,White
Mouse,Black
Pig,Black
```

Here is my code, nothing shows in my csv, I don't know why

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
data = { 'A': [ 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Pig'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
class Description(dict):
     def __missing__(self, key):
         return ''

desc = Description()
desc['Dog'] = 'White'
desc['Cat'] = 'White'
desc['Pig'] = 'White'
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: desc[x])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isin(["Dog","Cat"]), 'B'] = "White"
```

Then save:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

OR:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
```

see what you prefer

Comment: does't ouput in my csv :(

Comment: it's now replacing the black to white but the items that are not 'white' are deleted in my csv

Comment: @InUtero hmm... That's strange, can you please try again?

Comment: can this be done using variable? like animals ="dog", "cat" then df.loc[df['A'].isin([animals]), 'B'] = "White" ?

Answer (score 0):

Define a UDF and simply apply the function in the `A` column.

```
def surnamemap(x):
        if x =="dog":
             return 'Black'
        elif x == "cat":
             return 'White'


 df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: surnamemap[x])
```

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["Dog","Black"], ["Cat","White"]], columns=['A', 'B'])    
df.loc[df['A'] == "Dog", 'B'] = ["White"]
```

Comment: makes no output in my csv file

Comment: After that you have to save the new df to csv file